# iGraph won't plot from function - Python

Tags: python, igraph, canopy

So I'm setting up iGraph, and I'm having issues with the plot showing up.
The simple code is this

```
import iGraph
igraph.plot(igraph.Graph.Tree(127,2), layout='tree')
```

this will plot when i type it directly into python compiler (i'm using canopy)
But when trying to run it through the intpreter it does not display?

I assume this is a very basic issue but cannot seem to understand why it is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The Canopy GUI's default graphical backend is Qt. Most likely igraph uses a different graphical backend which conflicts with Qt. Try disabling Canopy's default Pylab mode in the Preferences dialog (Python tab). For more information, see https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469880